spyder error == EPERM || EUSERS || EINVAL || ENOSYS : No space left on device
in RHEL-8.10 with spyder located in /opt/anaconda3/bin/
where anaconda is from Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
when trying to run /opt/anaconda3/bin/spyder it core dumps immediately with this as the most relevant message
error == EPERM || error == EUSERS || error == EINVAL || error == ENOSYS. : No space left on device

can anyone elaborate on what these errors mean?  As for no space left on device the system does not have a swap partition, has 512GB of RAM, and has multiple partitions for /home and /var and /var/tmp and tmp.mount is enabled but a df -h shows none of them being over or close to 50% full.
I suspect the cause is some security setting I have applied, as I do have spyder working on identical rhel-8.10 server however with less security settings.  But I have yet to identify which security setting I might have applied to cause this.
This github page has details of the entire coredump text that I am experiencing : https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6901

This is really, really poor error reporting from whatever piece of code created that error message.

EPERM generally means you don't have permission to do something
EUSERS generally means "too many users"
EINVAL generally means "invalid argument"
ENOSYS means "invalid system call", i.e. trying to use a system call that does not exist.

Since these are generic POSIX error code values, one would have to check the source code for what system or library call was actually attempted, and then check the man page of that call for the detailed meaning of that error code when reported by that particular call.
Googling for the relevant parts of the error message, it seems the error might be coming from near the beginning (= line 100...140 or so depending on exact version) of credentials.cc which is a part of Chromium/QtWebEngine:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/aa99e0990143359527b93a52c69dc2ec1a939fb3/sandbox/linux/services/credentials.cc#114
// CHECK() that an attempt to move to a new user namespace raised an expected
// errno.
void CheckCloneNewUserErrno(int error) {
  // EPERM can happen if already in a chroot. EUSERS if too many nested
  // namespaces are used. EINVAL for kernels that don't support the feature.
  // Valgrind will ENOSYS unshare().  ENOSPC can occur when the system has
  // reached its maximum configured number of user namespaces.
  PCHECK(error == EPERM || error == EUSERS || error == EINVAL ||
         error == ENOSYS || error == ENOSPC);
}

In your case, ENOSPC was apparently already translated to its human-readable standard text: "no space left on device".
But the comment describes that the check happens after trying to move to a new user namespace. It even describes the possible meanings of the error codes in this context:

EPERM if you are already within a chroot() environment.
EUSERS if there are too many nested namespaces.
EINVAL if the kernel does not support the user namespace feature.
ENOSYS would happen if you are running the program under Valgrind.
ENOSPC if the configured maximum total number of user namespaces is being exceeded.

I cannot be sure if this is the right bit of code for your case because you omitted the beginning of the error message, which would include the source code filename and line number where the error was generated. But the error seems to be specific enough for this bit of Chromium.
I also assume that you are not doing something special like running your spyder in a chrooted environment or under the Valgrind debugging tool.
So the remaining possible causes would be: either your RHEL 8.x system is either hardened to disable the use of user namespaces, or you are hitting the configured maximum number of user namespaces.
You can check the configured value with:
/usr/sbin/sysctl user.max_user_namespaces

or even
cat /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces

You don't have to have root access for either command.
If either of those commands reports that the max_user_namespaces value is currently set to 0, then it is likely some security hardening has been applied to the system.
See this link for an example of security hardening instructions for this setting.
On a default, non-hardened RHEL 8.10, the default value of user.max_user_namespaces seems to be 14438 (in a small test VM; the default might be even larger on larger systems).

thanks for the info

this error was due to a security setting which was
# /etc/sysctl.conf

user.max_user_namespaces = 0

setting this to 5 or larger seems to stop the error and coredump from happening when starting spyder.
I do not know what the default number is, if there is any, or how to show it.

OK, you figured it out yourself just as I was finishing my answer. But since it looks like I dug a little bit deeper :-) I decided to post my answer anyway. Note that if the user namespaces were disabled for security reasons, you might want to have it documented that spyder legitimately uses the user namespaces, or else there might be questions if a security audit ever happens on that system.
